# Стоит, даже когда думаешь: «Ну это прям не может никак приозойти!»(,) — проверить

Tags: запятые

Нужна запятая?

> Стоит, даже когда думаешь: «Ну это прям не может никак приозойти!»(,) — проверить, т. к., есль этого не сделаешь, — возможно, будут слёзы, и много.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По [§ 51,](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=154) запятая не нужна. А тире лучше убрать, т. к. используется двойной союз ЕСЛЬ..., ВОЗМОЖНО. И нужно убрать запятую перед *есль*, потому что при двойном союзе перед первой его частью запятая не ставится. Получаем такой вариант:

***Стоит, даже когда думаешь: «Ну это прям не может никак приозойти!» — проверить, т. к. есль этого не сделаешь, возможно, будут слёзы, и много***.

Запятую из-за восклицательного знака поставить нельзя, заменяем ее тире. Ссылку я уже дал.

Можно также привести пример из его справочника:

*И только когда он шептал: «Мама! Мама!» — ему становилось как будто легче*.

Как видите, после кавычек нужна запятая, закрывающая придаточное, но восклицательный знак не даëт еë поставить, поэтому запятую заменяем тире.

Answer (score 1):

Предлагается **как вариант**:

***Стоит —  даже когда думаешь: «Ну это прям не может никак произойти!»**  — провЕрить, так как  если этого не сделаешь, возможно, будут слёзы, и много.*

**Пояснение**

1. Рассмотрим **упрощенное** предложение:

*Стоит — **даже когда думаешь о невозможном** — проверить это.*

Стоит проверить — **составное глагольное сказуемое**!  Разве это **не надо учитывать?**

Здесь **вставка** между **частями СОСТАВНОГО сказуемого**.

2. По этой же схеме оформляем предложение **с прямой речью**.

**Примечание**

Убираю (**под давлением** общественности) спорную запятую. Но теперь-то, Лео-мастер, **вы согласитесь со мной?**

Comment: Почему запятая после кавычек? Во-первых, там восклицательный знак не даëт еë поставить, во-вторых, ни первая часть, ни вторая не треюуют запятой между ними. Вставка просто разрывает СГС, а между ними запятой не нужно.

Comment: Вариант со вставкой хороший, но я бы не ставил эту запятую из-за интонации, т. к. она по сути нигде не требуется.

Comment: Запятая как бы не нужна, да? Но разве вы не видите смещенную вставку? В обычном сказуемом: стоит провЕрить. А у нас: стОит. И кто вам разрешил делить составное сказуемое? Здесь только вставка!  Насчет интонации я думала. Если не поставить вторую запятую, то вставка будет симметричной, а у нас этого нет.  Вариант НЕСТАНДАРТНЫЙ, как его решать по общим правилам!

Comment: Нельзя из-за воскл. знака запятую ставить! Более того, ставку любую можно в принципе с тире и двумя запятыми выделять, но этот вариант архаичен, что РАН говорит. Одно запятую, отнюдь не оправданную, никто не должен ставить, тем более если там воскл. знак!

Comment: (1) Если вы хотели придумать пример на тему этого правила, то он должен быть именно на эту тему. А ваше предложение не соответствует, увы! Вот я его и решаю иначе,  по его грамматике.  (2) Запятые и тире считать, конечно, нужно, кто бы спорил!  Все должно быть по правилам. Но когда мы учим правила, не мешает задуматься над смыслом этого правила. (3) Я с  интересом смотрю на ваши примеры-идеи, и как идеи они мне нравятся. Но в данном случае идея хороша, а пример нет, Так что можно воспользоваться идеей и задать свой вопрос. Один я уже задала, пожалуй, задам и другой?))

Comment: Как вы на это смотрите? Это же ваши идеи!  Честная игра или не очень?))  А зачем вы разделили составное глагольное сказуемое на две части?