# Нужна ли здесь вставная конструкция и как ее оформить?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире, вставная-конструкция, вставка

Есть предложение:

*Стóит (?) **даже когда думаешь о невозможном** (?) проверить это.*

Я думаю, что здесь нужно использовать **вставку**, ведь мы разделяем части составного глагольного **сказуемого**.

Но нужна ли дополнительная **запятая?** Если поставить только **два тире,** то вставка будет **симметричной**, а по произношению она явно **смещена** к левой части.

Но как же решить эту задачу **по правилу**?

Вопрос задан **[по этой теме](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/476522/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%88%D1%8C-%D0%9D%D1%83-%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82).**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Нужна ли здесь вставная конструкция и как ее оформить?**

Вы уже высказали своё мнение, и я с ним согласен: придаточное предложение не просто разрывает главное — оно «разделяет части составного глагольного сказуемого».

Как известно, [вставные конструкции](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=123) могут быть оформлены тремя способами:

*Стóит — даже когда думаешь о невозможном — проверить это.

Стóит (даже когда думаешь о невозможном) проверить это.

Стóит, даже когда думаешь о невозможном, проверить это.*

Запятые невыразительны, скобки могут показаться менее «художественными» знаками, чем тире (хотя они часто встречаются, что мы видим в примерах из справочника Розенталя).

> **Но нужна ли дополнительная запятая?**

Этот вопрос возникает только в варианте с тире. Считаю, что не нужна.

Ни о каком смещении вставки в ту или другую сторону в правилах не говорится. Есть только пункт о симметрии и, соответственно, «постановке запятой перед вторым тире, если перед первым тире стоит запятая» (но у нас совсем не такой случай). А в справочнике Лопатина сказано: «Такое выделение для современных текстов не характерно».
Вы пишете: «...по произношению она [вставка] явно **смещена** к левой части». Почему? Можно произнести как угодно. На мой взгляд, она никуда не смещена, одинаковые паузы с обеих сторон.
А если мы поставим запятую, то **составное глагольное сказуемое ещё больше расколется**.

Интонационный принцип здесь должен подчиниться грамматическому:
***Стоит проверить это***.

**P. S.:** Интересный пример у Розенталя:
*Но в конце хочу — **других желаний нету** — встретить я хочу мой смертный час так, как встретил смерть товарищ Нетте* (М.).
Здесь видим разрыв СГС, но в то же время и повтор ***хочу***. Странно, что нет запятых перед вторым тире, ведь есть такое:
*Встал Максим-то против дедушки — **а дед ему по плечи,** — встал и говорит…* (М. Г.) — играет роль повторение слова *встал*.

Comment: Спасибо за ваше внимание к теме, голос от меня. Вопросов осталось много, так что придется подумать.  Я по возможности запишу их в поле ответа.

Comment: Во втором случае союз А, а в первом бессоюзная вставка. А у нас ДАЖЕ вместо союза. Повтор "хочу" осложняет тему расчленения СГС, дальше: я хочу встретить, нет расчленения. Подозрительный Маяковский, у него все не как у людей.  Нам бы со своим Маяковским разобраться)

Comment: Союз А совсем ни при чём. Тогда и перед первым тире ставили бы запятую. У Маяковского нужна запятая перед вторым тире. Может, редакторы справочника пропустили (надо поискать в других источниках).

Comment: Как знать, может и при чем. При бессоюзной связи вероятность тире больше. Пропустили? Может быть. А может, она Маяковскому не понравилась)

Answer (score 0):

**Вопрос 1 (по ответу). Чем нехорош вариант с запятыми?**

1. **Сказуемое?** А его любая конструкция буде расчленять.
2. В данном случае **частица ДАЖЕ** может выполнять функцию **присоединительного** союза.  Интерпозиция конструкции всегда **вставочная,** разница только в длительности пауз. И если их не подчеркивать, то запятые ничуть **не хуже.**
3. **Ударение?** Предложение будет делиться на две части: вставка может уйти или налево, или направо. Это зависит от **контекста.** Симметрии здесь **не будет.**

(1) **СтОит, / даже когда думаешь о невозможном,** //  проверить это.

(2) Стоит, / даже когда думаешь о невозможном, //  **провЕрить это.**

Мы **слышим** это смещение? Разумеется, да.

4. А теперь увеличим **паузы** и перейдем к **вставной** конструкции. Вроде бы все тоже самое. **Или в чем разница?**

Comment: Да никакой разницы. Только в длительности пауз и графике. То есть что больше соответствует стилю изложения. Это предпочтение автора. И запятые ничуть не хуже, конечно. Скобки более всего выделят структуру и покажут, что запятых не надо. А главный-то вопрос как раз о запятой, **когда ставим тире:** она и здесь невозможна, потому что: *Стоит проверить это, даже когда думаешь о невозможном.*

Comment: Проверки не люблю, это другой синтаксис. Никакой разницы? Меня смещение интересует, есть или нет? Две части в предложении или три части?  И если разницы нет, то вставка при двух тире тоже смещена.

Comment: Деление на три части – 
 это утопия для нераспространенного предложения. А вот вставка – другое дело. Смещенная вставка!

Comment: Смещение, как я понимаю, это когда вставка относится по смыслу к той или другой части, а у нас просто придаточное вклинивается в главное. Интонационно мы можем отнести вставку туда, сюда или никуда. Но на пунктуацию это не повлияет, так как невозможно, здесь по крайней мере, идти против грамматики. // Нет трёх частей. Есть вставка и разрывное предложение.

Comment: Давайте  уж или или о грамматике, или об интонации, или о правилах. Вот я Максима спрашиваю: вы слышите смещенную вставку? Ответ: Может, и слышу, а знаки буду ставить по правилам. И немного психологии: мы видим только то, что нас научили видеть. Это наука! Слышим, наверное, тоже. Иногда и не знаем, что слышим)  О люди! Вы так удивительны!

Comment: Сначала смысл, от него создаётся структура (грамматика). Если последняя вариативна и не нарушается, тогда подключается интонация.

Comment: Ясен перец,  а вставка ведь смещена, согласны?   Произношение начинается с произношения. По смыслу, с учетом контекста.  И еще: вас надолго хватит?) А то это только первый вопрос...)

Comment: Никуда она не смещена. После ***стоит*** тоже можно сделать огромную паузу. // Я могу подолгу отсутствовать. Захожу сюда – и вижу кучу новых вопросов от одного и ответы от другого (двух), что даже не всегда можно успеть прочитать. Начинаешь читать – и глаза вянут от неаккуратности, невнимательности и повторов. А чтобы делать каждый раз замечания, тоже нужно время, да ещё с формулировками надо попыхтеть, чтобы сильно не задеть (удалить также не забыть, если прислушались).

Comment: Вы меня не так поняли) У меня не настолько много дерзости, чтобы я задала  вам вопрос  о вашем пребывании на сайте.  Я имела в виду другие вопросы по этому ответу.  И пока вы еще не совсем рассердились, я все-таки спрошу: могу я поставить два тире в теме у Лео? Сейчас там стоит одно тире.

Comment: Нет, я так и понял, что вопросы будут по этой теме. Я к тому, что могу не сразу ответить (занимаюсь другим делами, и сейчас тоже). Про одно тире не понял — там же вы два поставили. И правильно.

Comment: В принятом ответе у Максима первой стоит запятая, а не тире  Спасибо за ответ и за ваше внимание. Я стараюсь быть аккуратнее, но не всегда получается. Много тем, внимания на все не хватает: пишешь одно, думаешь о другом и т. д.

Comment: Отлично! Спасибо! У вас бывают только опечатки и разнокалиберное выделение в тех местах, где нужно одинаковое. Это меня не раздражает, и когда могу и хочу, я правлю.